# WCF extensions for VS 2005 for .NET 2.0 framework

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2005

Is it possible to use WCF extensions in .NET 2.0 framework? Well i tried to look for Add Service Reference in VS 2005 in .NET 2.0 framework, but found Add Web Reference only.
Tried svcutil.exe also to add WCF extension reference. But svcutil.exe is not recognized.
I think i need to download WCF extensions for VS 2005 for .Net 2.0 framework. 
Please suggest and provide the links to download WCF extensions for VS 2005 for .NET 2.0 framework
and not for .Net 3.0 framework.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Sorry.

Your only choice is to use .NET 3.0.   In case it helps...   .NET 3.0 uses the .NET 2.0 runtime.   So your existing code should continue to work.

Answer (score 0):

No, at least no supported way. When WCF was in development, there have been CTPs made available, that used VS 2005 (and thus .NET 2.0 I would assume). But the final bits have only been included with .NET 3.0 (and VS 2008). The CTP is since then, of course, no longer supported.

Even if you were still able to download the last of these CTP release, I would assume you cannot get them from Microsoft anymore, you still shouldn't use them.